# How to set Super/Windows key to Show All Applications menu in GNOME DE?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, antergos

I am on Antergos with GNOME 3.24.3.

Pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (Windows key) opens this Activities menu/view that I don't want to use:

[image: Activities menu]

Pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> keys opens the menu that I want to open with just the <kbd>Super</kbd> key:

[image]

I have attempted to set this myself by using `dconf-editor` to set the Activities menu to the <kbd>Alt_R</kbd> key (a key I never use) and the Show All Applications menu to the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

*(The keybinding for the Activities menu is under `/org/gnome/mutter/overlay-key`. The keybinding for the Show All Applications menu is under `/org/gnome/shell/keybindings/toggle-application-view`.)*

However, pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> does nothing now.

How can I make this all work?

Comment: I believe this extension will be helpful : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1198/start-overlay-in-application-view/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I configured those keys directly through Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard on Ubuntu 17.10. Under "System" section you have "Show the overview" which you can disable (by pressing backspace). And for "Show all applications" you can configure then Super.

Comment: Doesn't work on 18.04. I disabled that option but it still comes up when I hit the super key. Very very very annoying

Comment: Strange, works for me.

Comment: I thought it might have to do with the fact that I'm using a wireless keyboard but the native one doesn't work either. It's a bit glitchy on a few settings

Comment: This doesn't work on Manjaro Gnome, i had to use gsettings manually instead, following https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518458/54172 answer.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure why you couldn't get it working with those dconf settings. This works for me (in Ubuntu 18.04):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-application-view "['Super_L']"
```

Comment: I've been running Arch for awhile now and for whatever reason after a full update my super-key behavior changed, and yet digging through the settings I found nothing conflicting. Running both of these commands restored my super activities overview functionality.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I needed to figure out which key was mapped to the physical `super` key.

1. Launch `Settings -> Region & Language`.
2. Click on the `Input Sources` list and choose a language (in my case it was `English`).
3. Click on the little "keyboard" button in the right corner of the window and launch "Show keyboard layout".
4. Click `Super` button and figure out that it's mapped to `Super_R`
5. Run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "['Super_R']"`

All good now!

Comment: I Click "Super_L" button in the layout and nothing happends, but just using "Super_R" instead of "Super_L" make it work. Great!

Comment: @erm3nda you can launch tweaks and flip Super_L to Super_R as well (goto Keyboard & Mouse -> Overview Shortcut)

Comment: As far as i remember, the keyboard shortcuts do only accept a combination of keys, so i was not able to just set it to "Super_L" or "Super_R" as is. That's why i ended up using gsettings.

Comment: it's not the standard keyboard shortcuts app, it's the `tweaks` app (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks). It basically is the graphical way to set some gsettings

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS I've installed https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1198/start-overlay-in-application-view/
and done

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "['Super_L']"
```

Comment: I had to use `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ""` plus your command but it worked! :)

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME 42, install following extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5040/start-overlay-in-application-view/

For Ubuntu 17.1 or 20.04, install following extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1198/start-overlay-in-application-view/

Comment: This is the solution on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

For me, running Elementary OS, the below command worked:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "['Super_L']"
```

Answer (score 1):

For GNOME 3.34.4 in Manjaro, try this

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-application-view "['Super_L']"
```

Answer (score 0):

My custom shortcut key stopped working just now because of <kbd>Tab</kbd> key get stuck in my external keyboard. The **key get stuck** causes different combination keys and you may wonder why not working as expected.

So double check your keyboard for such case if keys not working.

Answer (score 0):

In gnome 3.36.4, mapping `Super_L` directly to an action using gsettings interfered with the keybindings involving `Super_L` as a modifier key (e.g., `Super+Space` to change input source) for me, which was annoying.

To get around this, I installed `xcape` and configured what pressing and releasing `Super_L` alone would do. In this case, one could set:

```
xcape -e "Super_L=Super_L|a"
```