# How to set single key for customization keyboard shortcuts in gnome

Tags: debian, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell, dconf

I'm trying to set single key to operate anything i want in gnome settings.

I'm using Debian-12 and Gnome 43.

Settings->Keyboard>View and Customize Shortcuts(Keyboard Shortcuts)->Custom Shortcuts->Add Shortcut->Set Shortcut

[image]

In Set Shortcut panel, single keys is not detected(neither model nor standard keys, i.e Super, Alt, CTRL, Shift etc. But Function keys could be detected i.e F1,F5...)

The thing I'm trying to do is to add single key and run any command by the shortcut or be able to change already available shortcuts by a single key i.e. pressing only `super` key should open application menu like in pressing in Windows key to open start menu.

So far, I've tried to change it by `dconf` editor and played around with settings;

> org > gnome > desktop > input-sources > sources

> org > gnome > desktop > input-sources > xkb-options

[image]

as in this [link](https://winaero.com/single-key-shortcut-change-keyboard-layout-gnome-3/) described but it didn't work.

Can you help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow these steps:

- Create your custom-keybinding (just use any shortcut keys, you are going to change it in the next step anyways)
- Open the dconf editor
- Go to `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/`
- Click on your newly created keybinding named `custom[::number::]`
- Go to `binding` and change the `Custom Value`

Thats it :)

---

P.S.: Well written question from you, I like it :)

Comment: Thank you very much :) I've tried but any shortcut doesn't work. I cannot open or run any command through those settings even by standard settings. Apparently, there is a problem. I'm gonna search and if i can resolve i'm gonna let you know.

Comment: I would recommend to check if it is a shortcut problem or a command problem. Try for example to put the shortcut to `b` and the command to `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`. I have tried it yesterday and worked on my PC :)

Comment: I couldn't find the problem. I think due to the some package I've removed before this operations so rolled back the system from backup. Now it's fixed. I can now change the shortcut. But there is another problem. I neither find the place where super key is used in the settings I've showed above gif video nor from conf editor.(I've searched and nothing appears). The behavior that I want to change is activities which shows all windows of applications that is running. But again thanks. Your answer is correct except some rare situations like this one.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for the problem which I mentioned in the comment under [Pixelbog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/515636/pixelbog)'s answer.

If you want to change any behavior(key-binding shortcut) that belongs to gnome shell and also if it doesn't exist in the `Settings->Keyboard>View and Customize Shortcuts(Keyboard Shortcuts)` you need to follow these steps:

1. Find the command(key binding feature) and it's path that you want to change it's shortcut in the terminal by using `gsettings list-recursively | grep SEARCH-TERM` command.
   https://askubuntu.com/questions/169704/how-to-search-dconf-for-keys-or-values
2. Go to the path in the `dconf` editor.
3. Change the shortcut however you like.

or if you don't want to use UI you can do as following.

1. Do above first step
2. And set new shortcut for the behavior you want to change by following `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-application-view "['Super_L']"`

[How to set Super/Windows key to Show All Applications menu in GNOME DE?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388238/how-to-set-super-windows-key-to-show-all-applications-menu-in-gnome-de)

NOTES:

1. If you want to change from multiple key bindings to only modal keys you need to do as following: from `['<Super_L>F10']` to `['Super_L']`
2. If you are trying to change a key-binding, which is belongs to an extension, you actually need to go to following path in `dconf` editor(since you may not find corresponding shortcut setting by following 2nd method on terminal, at least i couldn't): `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/EXTENSION-NAME/.../key-binding-settings` that you want to change